# Hiding IPs in JavaScript application

Tags: php, javascript

I'm working on JavaScript application, and to hide ip addresses in the client side, I use includes and requires, as follows:

In includes.php:

```
require ('C:/Program Files/Apache/Apache2.2/config.php');
```

In config.php:

```
<?php
$ServerURL = "http://192.168...:8080";
?>
```

and then my main html page, I typed at the top:

```
<?php 
include_once("app/common/includes.php");
```

and converted it to .php

and finally I had to retrieve the URL:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     var ServerURL = "<?php echo $ServerURL; ?>";
</script>
```

the thing is when I run the app, this line:

```
var ServerURL = "<?php echo $ServerURL; ?>";
```

appears in the client side like:

```
var ServerURL = "http://192.168...:8080";
```

it's supposed to be hidden

Comment: Why would it be hidden? You're echoing it out...

Comment: If the client can view the JavaScript (and it should be assumed *any* client that is sent the JavaScript *can* view it) .. they can view your "secret" (as well as the consequences of using it). Obfuscation and other indirects can slow people down, but otherwise ..

Comment: @elclanrs it should be hidden in the client side. for confidentiality purposes

Comment: @user2246674 So nothing I can do to hide it ?!

Comment: @Shadin Not if you send it to the client - also consider how the client uses it: if it used it to make a network request (or used in a link), don't even need to view the source code to see it. The only way to keep something truly confidential is to *not give it out* to the client. For instance, a server could act as a proxy and never relay the "real" server location.

Comment: @Shadin what is _confidentiality_ about your IP. If this is the internal network adress that is not reachable from outside then your implementation is broken (assuming the `ServerURL` is used to connect to your server). If it is the IP that your domain maps to then there isn't anything _confidentiality_ about that IP.

Comment: It seams you need a login area

Comment: If you hid the address from the client, how would it know what to connect to?

Comment: And, even if you *did* have some way to hide the IP in the web page, the user can always use his browser's developer tools to look at every connection his browser makes

Comment: It's absolutely no use to hide a private IP. 192.168.x.x are on a reserved C-class block, requests from outside with such an address as sender  will be zapped by any post-1990 router. Conversely, it's no use to show it on the Internet. Unless this is an intranet site, in that case people have access to more critical things than a private IP address.

Comment: Security through obscurity: that smells...

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it - every browser has some kind of functionality to view where it's ressources come from. Think of malware developers who were able to hide the URLs which host their malicious script code - that would be horrible.

The only thing you can do is: read the content from the remote server with PHP and echo it directly to the client.

Answer (score 1):

What you think is look like not possible. If you specify an url host in javascript. It would be viewable for user anyway. Only way I can suggest to user using a forward slash instead of complete host. Then source will show like that

```
var ServerURL = "/";
```

But one caveat that you must use virtual hosts on your local platform and application must not be deployed under directory. Otherwise url path will be mismatched and application will be not run due to 404 errors.

NOTE :  I am assuming ServerURL is current host under you site is working, Not any custom url used for any other purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit strange. If you really want to hide the Server's IP Address, You can make a PROXY as the middle man who communicates with the client and the real Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can encode the javascript file and make it tough for an attacker.
There is no guarantee that attacker will never break the encoding mechanism. If possible try to develop your own algorithm to encode java script files.

[Encode JS](http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/encode-decode.html) Please check this link.